# 'Using rvm to upgrade ruby' posts

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

There are TONS of these on stackoverflow, all of them recommending more or less the same solution (specify a value for --with-gcc option), but all with conflicting ideas of what exactly to do, and none of them containing a solution that works for the latest version of xcode on mountain lion (I eventually worked out I needed --with-gcc=gcc)

I wonder if someone with greater editorial rights than me would consider it worthwhile compiling all this noise into a post that attempts to explain how to configure rvm for use with different osx/xcode/ruby versions.

- [xcodebuild not finding gcc 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463724/xcodebuild-not-finding-gcc-4-2)
- [Can't install Ruby under Lion with RVM – GCC issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032824/cant-install-ruby-under-lion-with-rvm-gcc-issues)
- [Cannot compile ruby 1.9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592945/cannot-compile-ruby-1-9-3)
- [Can't compile 1.9.3 with rvm using gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579072/cant-compile-1-9-3-with-rvm-using-gcc)
- [make error when installing `ruby-1.8.7-p334` with `rvm` on Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168077/make-error-when-installing-ruby-1-8-7-p334-with-rvm-on-snow-leopard)
- [Error running make when installing Ruby 1.8.7-p302 via RVM on Mac OS 10.5.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338371/error-running-make-when-installing-ruby-1-8-7-p302-via-rvm-on-mac-os-10-5-8)
- [Using make on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469994/using-make-on-osx)
- [How do you install (build) Ruby 1.9.3 on OSX Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626729/how-do-you-install-build-ruby-1-9-3-on-osx-lion)
- [RVM ruby installation errors - Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813889/rvm-ruby-installation-errors-mac)

Comment: This may be a good candidate for a "self-answer".  Those that find it useful will vote accordingly on the question and answers.